# Solving mpc (model predictive control) on a microprocessor

Tags: model-predictive-control

I have a linear model dx/dt = Ax + Bu And I want to use model predictive control to control it. The sampling time is 100 microseconds and x is a vector with length 5 and u is a vector with length 6. Now I wanted to know if it is possible to implement this type of controller in a microcontroler ( with the horizon equal to 10)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should post this question on 
Electronics Stack Exchange site: https://electronics.stackexchange.com